# onbeforeunload - Cannot make changes to page UI

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

In my `onbeforeunload` function we are automatically disconnecting an ActiveX control from a server.
This process takes about 3 or 4 seconds (we have no control over that) so I want to display a message to let the user know that their refresh/navigate away/close window will happen as soon as the control disconnects. I don't want to make an `alert()` pop up, and just want to have an "asynchronous" message displayed to the user.

However, I can't seem to make any changes to the page's UI from within the `onbeforeunload`. I can't use a toast message class I have or even change a "status" `div`, as they don't seem to be doing anything.

Is this a limitation of the `onbeforeunload` function? Is my only option to use an `alert()`?

**Edit**
Code example:

```
function handleWindowOnBeforeUnload() {
    //alert('Disconnecting from client...');    //Would rather not use an alert()
    ShowToast('Closing connection...');         //Doesn't show
    $('#statusDiv').html('Auto-disconnect...'); //Neither does this
    //This is what takes ~4 seconds
    acx.stopConnection();
}
```

Comment: code example would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the `onbeforeunload` function.

To be honest this approach is flawed and you should look at changing your app to not need a `onbeforeunload` function.

You can detect a user disconnecting by long polling or web sockets if you need to disconnect something on the server. I am pretty sure this is the same for ActiveX.

Comment: The only problem is we don't have any control over the ActiveX, nor how the "server" interacts with it. The ActiveX is getting a stream from the server. If the ActiveX closes without calling disconnect, the server still thinks it is connected (it will time out after 90 seconds though, but that's too long). Looks like I'll have to use the `alert()`.